# Php json decode array

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have a json string. But i can not access values.

```
$json_string : '{"05526":[{"name":"rapertuar","surname":"xyz","notes":[{"mat1":"59","eng2":"60"},{"mat2":"59","eng2":"60"}]}]}';
$content = file_get_contents($json_string);
$json_a = json_decode($content, true);

echo $json_a['05526']['0']['name'];
echo $json_a['05526']['0']['name']['notes']['0']['mat1'];
```

How can i fix this code? Thank you

Comment: `file_get_contents($json_string)`? What is it?

Comment: Why do you try to access a file if you just have a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_string : '{"05526":[{"name":"rapertuar","surname":"xyz","notes":[{"mat1":"59","eng2":"60"},{"mat2":"59","eng2":"60"}]}]}';

// you don't need this line
//$content = file_get_contents($json_string);
$json_a = json_decode($json_string, true);

echo $json_a['05526']['0']['name'];
echo $json_a['05526']['0']['name']['notes']['0']['mat1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `file_get_contents` if you're storing the JSON in a string and then decoding it. Follow the below approach:

```
$json_string = '{"05526":[{"name":"rapertuar","surname":"xyz","notes":[{"mat1":"59","eng2":"60"},{"mat2":"59","eng2":"60"}]}]}';
$json_a = json_decode($json_string, true);

echo $json_a['05526']['0']['name']; // rapertuar
echo $json_a['05526']['0']['notes']['0']['mat1']; // 59
```